# Using PayPal API for ACH

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am currently using the PayPal NVP API, using the DoDirectPayment method, to accept credit card payments.  Is there a way to do something similar with ACH payments?

Answer (score 0):

ACH can be used as a funding source by buyers paying via PayPal. I.e. they can have the bank added inside their PayPal account.

But if you want to more directly process ACH payments through your site and be responsible for waiting to see whether the payments go through or not (since ACH takes time), you will need something like the Payflow gateway and a relationship with an ACH processor such as NORWEST. That's just one common option I've heard of, there surely must be others. This is more a question for some Google research than Stack Overflow.